# How to create sub md files with content that applies to the page md files

Tags: jekyll

I'm creating a website using Jekyll.
so far I have four pages which are created automatically from four md files which md files are in the root of the project.

```
index.md
about.md
login.md
register.md
```

Here is the content inside my `login.md file`

```
---
layout: layout-default
title: some login title
permalink: /login
theme: secondary-theme 
nav:
    menu-items:
        - type: text
          text: Don't have an account?
        - type: link
          text: SIGN UP
          class: button
          linkPath: /register
sections:
    - type: 3
      class: form-section
      header-line-2: Login Section!
      form:
        api: http://127.0.0.1:8080/login
        submit-text: LOG IN
        form-controls:
            - label-text: EMAIL ADDRESS
              input-type: email
              input-placeholder: Enter your email
              input-name: email
            - label-text: PASSWORD
              label-link-text: Forgot password?
              label-link-path: #
              input-type: password
              input-placeholder: Enter your password
              input-name: password

---
```

What i do is iterating the sections and applying html attribute values depending on the variables inside each section. That way i can have as many sections rendered as i want on one page. And they can also be different depending on the classes and content i put in the md file.
The problem is that if the project gets too complicated with different styles for sections and so on. I would like to separate each section content. It would be nice if i could make a folder lets say login/sections folder
and then put md files inside and then inside login.md file include these section md files. This way the code would be much more organized.
Is there way to do that, and is my approach actually good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll provides the ability to [include files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) into another files. The magic directory for this is `_includes`. Example:

If you create a file named `_includes/sections/s1.html`, you can include that **into any other file** with the following tag:

```
{% include sections/s1.html %}
```

This approach works for:

- including HTML file into HTML
- including HTML file into Markdown (since Markdown can contain HTML code)
- including Markdown into Markdown

If you want to include a Markdown file into a HTML, you have to use some trick:

```
{% capture m %}{% include sections/s1.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ m | markdownify }}
```

Comment: but I use _includes folder for HTML layouts.
What i want is to include md files inside md file and use the included content

Comment: You can use includes for Markdown files too. I added some clarification, hope it helps. If you don't want to use the `_includes` folder but another one, you can use `include_relative` tag too (see the linked docs).